# Get value from multimensional array using JSON.stringify and json_decode

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, multidimensional-array, stringify

I will read my multidimensional array  from jquery ajax using JSON.stringify and json_decode but my code is not working, can someone help me?

This is my ajax function

```
$(document).on('click', '#save-module', function() {
  var input_form = {};
  $('#module-option-form').find('input').each(function() {
    var input_name = $(this).attr('name');
    var input_value;
    if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
      if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        input_value = 1;
      } else {
        input_value = 0;
      }
    } else {
      input_value = $(this).val();
    }
    input_form.data.push({
      name: input_name,
      value: input_value
    });
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      action: "save_module_input",
      input_form: JSON.stringify(input_form)
    },
    success: function(result) {
      var input_form_stringify = JSON.stringify(input_form);
      console.log(input);//console log 1
      console.log(input_form_stringify);//console log 2
      console.log(result);//console log 3
    }
  });
});
```

and this is my php code

```
function save_module_input(){
        $input_form = json_decode($_POST['input_form']);
        echo $input_form->data[0]->name;
        echo $input_form->data[0]->value;
        exit(); 
    }
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_module_input', 'save_module_input' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_module_input', 'save_module_input' );
```

The result from first console log is like this

[image: consolelog1]

and the result from second console log is like this

[image: consolelog2]

but when I check the result from third console log is nothing. And I dont know how to check my array in php without sendback to javascript. I dont know where is the false

Comment: try to seee what happens when you only use `input_form` in the `data` part.Don't use `action` as both `action` and `input_form` will be sent through your $_POST. Do that to see if `action` is not mixing up things

Comment: sory, I cant do that, because in wordpress, ajax code is spesific, and **ajax function** just can to call with **action** in **data** post

Comment: If you open the Network tab of your developer tools, then fire your ajax, and click on the request, what do you see in the "Reponse" tab?

Comment: I using google chrome, and this is the response tab of this ajax [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/MAcXf.png) and this is all of header tab [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/vvyr7.png), [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztbdw.png), [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/UMCzi.png)